# AWS Cloudformation Create-Stack Template Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

So I'm trying to throw up a few resources in CF for an API. I have the below yml file, but I keep getting a template error and can't see the issue.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: 'container cluster on ECS, loadbalancer, security groups and cloudwatch'

Resources:

  ECSCluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
    Properties:
      ClusterName: 'hello-cluster'

  LoadBalancer:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Name: ecs-services
      Subnets:
        #these imports will pull from export name of the vpc stack that we made
        - 'subnet-abcdefg'
        - 'subnet-abcdefo'
        - 'subnet-abcdefp'
      SecurityGroups:
        #references the LoadBalancerSecurityGroup below
        - !Ref LoadBalancerSecurityGroup

  #port 80 for POC, then add 443
  LoadBalancerListener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      #references LoadBalancer above
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref LoadBalancer
      Protocol: HTTP
      Port: 80
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: forward
          #references target group below
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref DefaultTargetGroup

  #this is very open, we won't want this
  LoadBalancerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Security group for loadbalancer to services on ECS
      VpcId: 'vpc-abcdefg'
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          IpProtocol: -1

  DefaultTargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      Name: default
      #imports vpc export name from previous stack
      VpcId: 'vpc-abcdefg'
      Protocol: 'HTTP'
      Port: '80'  

  #extranious for now
  CloudWatchLogsGroup:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: 'apis'
      RetentionInDays: 1

  ## security group for containers simliar to load balancer getting connections from the internet,
  ## this will allow connections from the load balancer
  ContainerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup      
    Properties:
     VpcId: 'vpc-abcdefg'
     GroupDescription: for ecs containers
     SecurityGroupIngress:
       - SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref 'LoadBalancerSecurityGroup'
         IpProtocol: -1


Outputs:

  Cluster:
    Value: !Ref ECSCluster
    Export:
      Name: 'ECSCluster'

  Listener:
    Description: listener port 80
    Value: !Ref LoadBalancerListener
    Export:
      Name: 'Listener'

  ContainerSecurityGroup:
    Description: container security group
    Value: !Ref ContainerSecurityGroup
    Export:
      Name: 'ContainerSecurityGroup'

  LoadBalancerDNS:
    Description: Domain name for the loadbalancer
    Value: !GetAtt LoadBalancer.DNSName
    Export:
      Name: 'DomainName'
```

When I run this to create my stack, it gives me an error.

```sh
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name app-cluster --template-body file://infra/app-cluster.yml
```

The error is: `An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Invalid template property or properties [???AWSTemplateFormatVersion]`

When I remove the first two lines and have my first line be "Resources" I get this error `An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Template format error: At least one Resources member must be defined.`

Feel like I have to be missing something simple, but I'm just not seeing it. Thanks

Comment: I've tried to create your template using the UI and it's working.. It looks like an issue with the AWS CLI command. my guess is the YAML been corrupted somehow.

Comment: Checked using the cli as well and it's working, your file is corrupted 100%

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The three "???" signifies you have [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in your file.

Please save the template file as UTF-8 (without BOM) and it should fix the issue. This will depend on your [editor](https://www.hesk.com/knowledgebase/index.php?article=87).

Comment: Thanks. I was going crazy trying to figure what was wrong with the script itself!